# pyqt5 - QSQLTable model not committing new inserted row

Tags: pyqt5

I have the code shown below where in the first form there's a QTableView filled according to QSQLTable modelthe insertion. Upon the click of a QPushbutton widget, another form is displayed to insert new row in a db table (SQLite).

The problem I get is that the row is not inserted in the table as the submitAll() method does not work.

Where is my fault ?
Thanks for any hints

```py
class MainWindow(QWidget, Ui_f_tabella):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.w = None  # No external window yet.
        self.setWindowTitle("Gestione Risorse Interne")
        self.pb_Ins.setText("Inserimento Nuova Risorsa Interna")

        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("tb_RisorseInterne")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)

        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "CDL")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Desc_CDL")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Tipo")
        self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Desc_2")
        self.model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Costi")
        self.model.setHeaderData(5, Qt.Horizontal, "Troncone")
        self.model.setHeaderData(6, Qt.Horizontal, "BarraUtile")
        self.model.setHeaderData(7, Qt.Horizontal, "SovrametalloPerTaglio")
        self.model.setHeaderData(8, Qt.Horizontal, "CambioUtensile")
        self.model.setHeaderData(9, Qt.Horizontal, "TempoCSAutomatico")
        self.model.setHeaderData(10, Qt.Horizontal, "TempoRiposizCreSecPass")
        self.model.setHeaderData(11, Qt.Horizontal, "TempoRiposizCreCaricMANUALE")
        self.model.setHeaderData(12, Qt.Horizontal, "NrGiriMax-RPM")

        self.model.select()

        self.tView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.SingleSelection)
        self.tView.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)

        self.pb_Ins.clicked.connect(self.inserimento_ri)


def inserimento_ri(self):
    if self.w is None:
        self.w = InserimentoRisorsaInterna()
        self.w.show()
        self.w.pb_conf.clicked.connect(self.conferma_inserimento_risorsa_interna)
    else:
        self.w.close()
        self.w = None  # Discard reference, close window.


def conferma_inserimento_risorsa_interna(self):
    """Aggiunta nuova risorsa"""

    self.data = []
    for field in (self.w.lE_cdl, self.w.lE_descCDL, self.w.lE_tipo, self.w.lE_desc2,
                  self.w.dSB_costi, \
                  self.w.sB_troncone, self.w.sB_barra_utile, self.w.sB_sovrametallo, \
                  self.w.dSB_cambio_utensile, self.w.sB_tempo_carico_auto, \
                  self.w.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass, self.w.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man, \
                  self.w.sB_nr_giri_max):

        if not field.text():
            QMessageBox.critical(
                self,
                "Errore!",
                f"Inserimento non consentito per mancanza di informazioni"
                # f"Inserire il valore {field.objectName()}",
            )
            self.data = None  # Reset .data
            return

        self.data.append(field.text())

    if not self.data:
        return

    rows = self.model.rowCount()
    self.model.insertRows(rows, 1)
    for column_index, field in enumerate(self.data):
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(rows, column_index + 1), field)

    self.model.submitAll()
    self.model.select()


class InserimentoRisorsaInterna(QDialog, Ui_InsRisorseInterne):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Update - I found the issue in the statement 'self.model.setData(self.model.index(rows, column_index + 1), field)' as the column number should be set to column_index and not to column_index + 1 otherwise it does not set the value of the key field of the table which has a 'NOT NULL' constraint

Comment: The problem is not only that, but also the fact that the column index would be wrong anyway and the last `setData()` will return `False` since you're trying to access a non existing column. Note that QSqlTableModel has a [`record()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#record) function that returns an empty [QSqlRecord()](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlrecord.html) which you could use to fill the data for the new row. I also suggest you to create a tuple with the list of widgets in the `__init__` instead of recreating it every time (also, using the parentheses, there is no need for `\`)

Comment: @musicamente: thanks for your comment. I will use the record() function as per your suggestion to handle the new record insertion. As I'm newbie in PyQT I'm not sure to have got your hint about creating a tuple with the list of widgets. Could you please show how you would change that part of the code ? Thanks for supporting

Comment: That's not related to PyQt, it's just python convenience: create a tuple as an instance attribute that contains all those widgets in the init, so you only do `for field in self fields:`, which also makes the code more readable.